# Necessary and sufficient conditions for $F$ to be a joint cdf (from Grimmett & Stirzaker)

Tags: probability-theory

This question arose from reading Grimmett & Stirzaker, *Probability and Random Processes*, Ch 2. They say that the following 3 conditions are jointly necessary and sufficient for $F$ to be a distribution function (what they call CDFs):

1. $\lim_{x\to-\infty} F(x) = 0, \lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = 1$
2. if $x<y$ then $F(x)\leq F(y)$
3. $F$ is right-continuous, that is, $F(x+h)\to F(x)$ as $h\downarrow 0$

Now, there are corresponding conditions, which look very similar, for joint distribution functions:

1. $\lim_{x,y\to-\infty} F_{X,Y}(x,y) = 0, \lim_{x,y\to\infty} F_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1$
2. if $(x_1,y_1)\leq (x_2,y_2)$ then $F_{X,Y}(x_1,y_1)\leq F_{X,Y}(x_2,y_2)$
3. $F_{X,Y}$ is continuous from above, that is, $F_{X,Y}(x+u, y+v)\to F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ as $u,v\downarrow 0$

After this definition they **don't** say that these conditions are jointly necessary and sufficient.

Now, consider the possible d.f.
$$ F(x,y)= 
\begin{cases}
1-e^{-x-y}, & \text{if}\ x,y\geq 0 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

This satisfies, as far as I can tell, the conditions above for joint d.f.s. However, we have that $ \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x \partial y} <0 $, so clearly this cannot be a valid d.f.

So what's going on here? Am I wrong that the function above satisfies the 3 conditions? Or is it that while the 3 conditions are necessary and sufficient for the single-variable case, they are not so for joint d.f.s? If so, I'd welcome any insight into why this is the case.

PS: Mechanically I do see that the problem arises because one ``differentiates twice'' for the joint case; this produces a function of the form $-e^{\dots}$ which cannot be a pdf. The single-variable equivalent $1-e^{-x}$ does not have this problem.

PPS: I know very little probability except for what I've read from G&S so far, so I might be getting something very basic quite wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing condition is that the measure of half-open rectangles $(a,b] \times (c,d]$ should be nonnegative, i.e., if $a<b$ and $c<d$ then we must have
$$ F(b,d)-F(a,d)-F(b,c)+F(a,c) \ge 0 \,.\tag{4}$$

Indeed, clearly (1)-(4) are necessary. If they hold, then we can define a measure $\mu$ on the semiring of half open rectangles by
$$\mu \Bigl((a,b] \times (c,d]\Bigr):= F(b,d)-F(a,d)-F(b,c)+F(a,c)   \tag{4}$$ and extend it via the Caratheodory extension theorem to a Borel measure that we still call $\mu$. Then   the random variable $(x,y)$ on the probability space $\Bigl({\mathbb R}^2, \text{Borel}, \mu \Bigr)$ has distribution function $F$.

Comment: Upon reading your comment I thought, "I've seen this before". And indeed I had; it's an exercise in G&S (If X and Y have d.f. F, show that the property (4) holds), and I had even done that exercise! But hadn't connected it to the question at hand. That covers the necessary part. As for sufficiency, I don't yet have the measure theory background to fully (or even mostly) understand the Extension Th, but I've made a note of it and will come back to it later. Indeed, Rosenthal's book, which is next on my reading list, covers it in Ch 2. All this to say, thanks! Your comment got me unstuck.